# how to reset variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math, random

this is the code

```
var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
setInterval(function () {

    if (x >= 5) {
          $('.test').show();
          setTimeout(function () {
                         $('.test').hide();
                 }, 2000);
    } else {
        x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    }

}, x * 1000);
```

this code show `.test` with the same random like if the `x=8` it will stay 8 and doesn't change what I really want is changing `x` to another number

I've tried to put `var x` in the local scope and it show me `x` in `setInterval` is undifined

I wanna `$('.test')` shows in a random way between 5 and 10 second like first time shows after 7S and second time shows after 9 second, etc... .

Comment: well the interval is not going to adjust, it will be whatever it was the first time it runs.

Comment: so what I want can't be achieved?

Comment: I put variable as the timing of 'Interval'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime the delay to show is different with this snippet.

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function showDiv(x){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.test').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.test').hide();
      x = getRandomArbitrary(5, 10)
      showDiv(x)
    }, 2000);
  }, x * 1000);
}

var x = getRandomArbitrary(5, 10)
showDiv(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="display: none">test</div>
```

Comment: but can you tell me why you use (25 - 5) + 5 I get confused

Comment: `Math.random() * (max - min)` will result in a random number from 0 to `max - min`. So I have to add `+ min` to achieve from `min` to `max`. Got it?

Comment: Order of operations

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout, setInterval will only run at the interval you first called it with. setTimeout only fires once and then you can have it call again with another random variable.

```js
roll();

function roll() {
  var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (x >= 5) {
      $('.test').show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.test').hide();
      }, 2000);
    }
    roll();
  }, x * 1000);
}
```

```css
.test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Test div</div>
```

Comment: it is the same result that I have in 'setInterval'

Comment: Put a console.log on the x and you will see it is different each iteration. It is working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to rearrange your code and create a function that will call itself with `setTimeout()`. Forget about `setInterval()` for this... Like **epascarello** mentioned in a commentary, the second argument of the `clearInterval()` (the milliseconds of the interval) will be configured one time when your code start running and the function will be called every `N` milliseconds, where `N` is that initially configured interval.

```js
var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );

function test(x)
{
    console.log(x);

    if (x > 5)
    {
        $('.test').show();
        setTimeout(() => $('.test').hide(), 2000);
    }

    x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 25 );
    setTimeout(() => test(x), x * 1000);
}

test(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" style="display:none; background:skyblue">TEST</div>
```

Comment: @MuntadarMuhammad you are welcome, consider to up-vote all the answers that were useful to you when you reach enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
setInterval(function () {

    if (x >= 5) { // because of this, you get the same number for x. if x >= 5 then the x won't change in this block and has the last value forever.
          $('.test').show();
          setTimeout(function () {
                         $('.test').hide();
                 }, 2000);
    } else {
        x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 );
    }

}, x * 1000);
```